# couple of batch files in one batch wait and failmail

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Batching files one after another..
These three batch files complete one task

my requirement is

```
call a.bat - takes about 20 minues, so it has to wait so timeout cmd is good in batch?
if it fails go to end
call b.bat - takes about 5 minutes, so it has to wait
if it fails go to end
call c.bat - takes about 1 hour, so it has to wait
```

And I need have a mail in place when any batch fails.

can I have efficient code for the same please?

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Batch files automatically wait for a called batch to complete before continuing. So all you need to worry about is aborting upon error. The conditional `||` operator will execute the subsequent command only if the prior command failed.

I'm assuming your called batch routines properly return an error code upon failure.

```
@echo off
call a.bat||goto failure
call b.bat||goto failure
call c.bat||goto failure
exit /b

:failure
REM code to send failure email goes here
```

I will leave it to you to Google for answers on how to send an email from a batch script.